# Issue when knitting R Markdown File - Variables not recognised

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having issues referencing the output of a group by statement in R when knitting a markdown file. When I refer the variable name of the output of a group_by and summarise statement, I get an error saying the variable doesn't exist.

Below is a version of the code that works when run in R Studio but fails in R Markdown.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(name = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1" ),
              s_id = c("ab", "ab", "cd", "ab", " bc", "ab"),
              t_id = c("12A", "12A", "12A", "14B", "14B", "14B"))


breakdown <- DF1 %>%
  group_by(name, s_id) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(t_id))


breakdown_v2 <- mutate(.data = breakdown, 
                               number_of_trips = ifelse (s_id == 'ab', (count*5), 
                                                                  ifelse (s_id == 'cd', (count*2), (count*1))))
```

Something similar happened to me previously, which led me to explicitly stating the s_id in the summarise statement, but it won't work for me this time.

Any idea? 
Thanks

Update: Actual Code Used:

````
```{r Busiest/Quietest Routes}
# I needed to find the number of distinct trips per service before multiplying out the trips per week. 

distinct_trips_breakdown <- Overall_Dublin_Bus_Record %>%
  group_by(route_short_name, service_id) %>%
    summarise(count = n_distinct(trip_id))

distinct_trips_breakdown <- mutate(.data = distinct_trips_breakdown, 
                                number_of_trips_per_week = ifelse (service_id == '1', (count*5), ifelse (service_id == '2', (count*2), (count*1))))

Overall_trips_per_week <- distinct_trips_breakdown %>%
  group_by(route_short_name) %>%
    summarise(total_trips_per_week = sum(number_of_trips_per_week))

Busiest_Routes <- top_n(Overall_trips_per_week, 5)
Quiestest_Routes <- top_n(Overall_trips_per_week, -5)

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error in the end. The issue was not when loading up plyr before dplyr...Solved it by putting dplyr:: before summarise.

````
```{r }

DF1 <- data.frame(name = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1" ),
              s_id = c("ab", "ab", "cd", "ab", " bc", "ab"),
              t_id = c("12A", "12A", "12A", "14B", "14B", "14B"))


breakdown <- DF1 %>%
  group_by(name, s_id) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count = n_distinct(t_id))


breakdown_v2 <- mutate(.data = breakdown, 
                               number_of_trips = ifelse (s_id == 'ab', (count*5), 
                                                                  ifelse (s_id == 'cd', (count*2), (count*1))))
```
````

Answer (score 0):

For me the code works fine. Could you write exactly your code chunk ? It might be a problem of spaces or that you did not put the 3 ``` to end the chunk down. Also, remember to load the packages. Try to use the following chunk, which works for me (having loaded the packages):

````
```{r }

DF1 <- data.frame(name = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1" ),
              s_id = c("ab", "ab", "cd", "ab", " bc", "ab"),
              t_id = c("12A", "12A", "12A", "14B", "14B", "14B"))


breakdown <- DF1 %>%
  group_by(name, s_id) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(t_id))


breakdown_v2 <- mutate(.data = breakdown, 
                               number_of_trips = ifelse (s_id == 'ab', (count*5), 
                                                                  ifelse (s_id == 'cd', (count*2), (count*1))))
```
````

`

Cheers!

Comment: Hey dude, I just updated  my question. Could the issue lie when you paste the normal code from R Studio into a markdown type layout?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the second part of the code. As far as I know, I have just tried to copy paste other code into Rmarkdown from RStudio and I am not having that problem.  Cheers!